# how to execute a method(having INSERT and UPDATE operations) non-transactionally with spring-hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am facing an issue that some column value is getting updated wrongly in DB. But we are not able to identify the where it is happening. To identify this issue, i am trying to execute my method non-transactionally. I have commented my method pattern under transaction advice in spring's `applicationContext-hibernate.xml` file  and also enabled `autcommit` as true as below.

```
<!-- <tx:method name="do*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="DelegatorException"/> -->

<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
```

but its giving below exception. **Note:** Using `spring-orm-5.2.4.jar` and `hibernate-core-5.3.20.jar`.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.20.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/:5.3.20.Final-redhat-00001]
```

Comment: Have you tried other propagation values like NEVER or NOT_SUPPORTED?

Comment: Thanks @dimirsen for your reply. i have even tried with NEVER and also NOT_SUPPORTED. Still its not working. Not sure where it is wrong. In 'hibernate 4.2' and 'spring 3.2' versions, i could able to execute a method non-transactionally with 'autocommit' as true. But with 'hibernate-core-5.3.20.jar' and 'spring-orm-5.2.4.jar' its not working